# Flutter WebSocket disconnects after sending a message

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets, websocket

I'm experiencing an issue with a WebSocket connection in my Flutter app. The connection gets disconnected immediately after sending a message through the WebSocket. I'm using the `web_socket_channel` package for WebSocket communication.

Here's an overview of my code:

here is the socket controller class, I'm using `provider` state management

```dart
// UserSocketController
class UserSocketController extends ChangeNotifier {
  WebSocketChannel? channel;

  void connect() {
    final url = Uri.parse(ApiEndpoints.chatSocket);
    final token = 'Firebase ${AppConfig.globalFirebaseToken}';
    final headers = {'Authorization': token};

    channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(url, headers: headers);

    channel?.stream.listen(
      (message) {
        print('Connected: $message');
      },
      onDone: () {
        print('Disconnected');
      },
      onError: (error) {
        print('Error: $error');
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> sendMessage({
    required String message,
    required int id,
    required MessageType type,
  }) async {
    try {
      final body = {
        "type": 3,
        "recipient": id,
        "text": message,
      };
      final Map<String, dynamic> request = {
        'headers': {
          'Authorization': "Firebase ${AppConfig.globalFirebaseToken}"
        },
        'body': body,
      };

      final String jsonData = json.encode(request);

      channel?.sink.add(jsonData);

      log('Message sent successfully: $request');
    } catch (e) {
      log('Error on sending message: $e');
    }
  }

  void disconnect() {
    channel?.sink.close();
  }
}
```

here is where i'm calling the `connect` function to connect websocket

```dart
// RouteScreen
class RouteScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RouteScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RouteScreen> createState() => _RouteScreenState();
}

class _RouteScreenState extends State<RouteScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      final webSocketProvider = Provider.of<UserSocketController>(context, listen: false);
      webSocketProvider.connect();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: AppBottomNavigationBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that the WebSocket connection gets disconnected immediately after sending a message using the `sendMessage()` method. The "Disconnected" message is printed in the `onDone` callback of the WebSocket stream.

I expect the WebSocket connection to remain active even after sending a message. How can I fix this issue and maintain the WebSocket connection?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!